# Homomorphisms preserve solubility of groups, and some others.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

**Definition**: Let $G$ be a group. A **subnormal series** for G is a chain of subgroups
$1 = G_0 \subseteq G_1 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq G_n = G$ such that $G_i$ is normal in $G_{i+1}$ for $i = 0,1, ..., (n-1).$

We call a group **soluble** if it has a subnormal series and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian for $i = 0,1, ..., (n-1).$

First of all, i've been told the following lemma is useful.

*Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup. Then $G/N$ is abelian if and only if $[g,h] \in N$ for all $g, h \in G$.*

I want to prove points (ii), (iii) and (iv) of the following (I have included point (i), which used the above lemma, in case it helps see what kind of path I should be taking):

*(i) Subgroups of soluble groups are soluble.*

*(ii) If $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and G is soluble then Im($\phi$) is
soluble.*

*(iii) Quotient groups of soluble groups are soluble (i.e. if $N$ is a normal
subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is soluble then $G/N$ is soluble).*

*(iv) If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and both $N$ and $G/N$ are soluble
then $G$ is soluble.*

Comment: Which definition of soluble do you use?

Comment: Ah. Of course! I'll add it to the above.

Comment: Do you see that (ii) and (iii) are really the same claim?

Comment: Is it related to first isomorphism theorem in some way?

Comment: It is pretty much exactly the first isomorphism theorem (assuming we use the same numbering of those theorems).

Comment: the below seems to confirm this :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that ii and iii are equivalent since $Im(\phi)\cong G/Ker(\phi)$. To prove this, just take the subnormal series for $G$ and project it onto $G/N$, which should preserve normality and abelianness of consecutive quotients (you can check that the commutator of $G_{i+1}/N$ is contained in $G_i/N$).

For iv, since subgroups of $G/N$ correspond to subgroups of $G$ containing $N$, you can build a series from $1$ to $N$, and then use the series from $1$ to $G/N$ to get a series from $N$ to $G$, which you can combine with the other one to get a series from $1$ to $G$.

Comment: I don't fully get the method for (iv), and what you mean by "project it onto G/N" 
Once I understand what you mean by these two things, i'll have got it. This is good stuff!

Comment: So you have the projection map $G\to G/n$ which sends $g\mapsto gN$, and is a homomorphism. If $N$ is normal in $G$, then the image of $N$ under this projection map should be normal in $G/N$.

Also, if you have a subgroup of $G/N$, then its preimage under this map is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$. This gives the correspondence I mentioned, and the correspondence preserves properties like normality.